# Error while running C program

Tags: c, string

I am trying to make a program that inserts 'abc' into a string.
What is the problem with this code? I can not find a mistake.

```
// Elvis’s hip and happening ABC-printing code

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_ABC_LET 27
char makeABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET]);

int main(void)
{
    char abcString[NUM_ABC_LET] = "";

    makeABC(abcString);

    puts(abcString);

    return (0);
}

char makeABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET])
{
    char letter = ' ';

    for (letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++)
    {
        strncat(abc, letter, NUM_ABC_LET);
    }

    return abc;
}
```

Comment: You are treating `char` and `char *` as same in your function arguments and return type. Understand the difference between them and your problem should get solved.

Comment: Are you saying that code compiles without errors?! If not, you don't need to find the mistake, because compiler finds it for you and tells you what to fix. If you have trouble understanding what compiler tells you, then ask about *that*.

Answer (score 2):

> strncat(abc, letter, NUM_ABC_LET);

Problem is with your `strncat`, the 2nd param needs to be a const string, but here you have it as a single char.

For your case, I think it'd be better to use `snprintf`. So instead of `strncat`, you can use this in your loop:

```
int pos = letter - 'a';
snprintf(abc + pos, NUM_ABC_LET - pos, "%c", letter);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are passing to `strncat` a char instead of char* (a character instead of the address of it)

here is strncat prototype:

```
char *strncat(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);
```

it copies `n` chars from a string (char*) to another one

what strncat did with your code was trying to find what is at address 'a' (97)
and sent you a segfault because the address 97 does not belong to your program so it crashed.
instead you should tell him where is the variable (example 2)
the most important is to understand how memory work in C

you did not need strncat for this purpose so here is a version without one:

```
char makeABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET])
{
  int   x;

  x = 0;
  while (x < NUM_ABC_LET)
    {
      abc[x] = x + 'a';
      x += 1;
    }
  return abc;
}
```

and a version with it:

```
char makeABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET])
{
  char letter = ' ';

  for (letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++)
    {
      strncat(abc + letter - 'a', &letter, 1);
    }

  return abc;
}
```

or you could just have done

```
char makeABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET])
{
  strncat(abc, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", NUM_ABC_LET);
  return abc;
}
```